# From two functions create a tuple transform

Tags: haskell

What I am trying to do is that from a function, f, returning a pair. I want to make a pair of two functions, pf. And than implement the transform f2p.

```
f :: a -> (b,c)
pf :: (a->b,a->c)
f2p :: (a -> (b,c)) -> (a->b,a->c)
```

I find this surprisingly difficult, I think I should use function composition in some manner but the question seems so strangely formulated. What I have tried is just to create a dummy function for f looking like this.

```
f n = (n,n+1)
```

just to be able to work with the two other functions. But when I come to write the function pf, whatever I do I can not make it work like the definition want it to. For example,

```
pf = (fst a, snd a)
     where a = f 3
```

This just makes it into pf :: (Integer, Integer), which is not really what I want. If I try to force it with pf :: (Num t) => (t->t,t->t) I get

> Could not deduce (Num (t -> t)) arising from a use of ‘f’

I really need some guidance!

Comment: Do you know what `\x -> ...` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a = f x` and `f :: T -> (B, C)`, then `a` is already a `(B, C)` and not a function anymore. We only get a `B` or a `C` out of it, but we cannot plug in another `T`.

So we need to build two functions from `f` instead, such that

```
firstF x  = fst (f x)
secondF x = snd (f x)
```

Actually, we're done at that point:

```
pf = (firstF, secondF)
```

We can now write `f2p`:

```
f2p :: (a -> (b,c)) -> (a -> b, a -> c)
f2p f = (fst . f, snd . f)
```

Comment: Thank you! Are going to check your answer as the solution asap.